# Show special Price when swatch color for customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, catalog-price-rules

System: Magento 1.9.3.1

What we need: We want to show in the product view if the customer (who is grouped in 10% discount customer group) chooses white or black the special price. In our shopping cart there is the discount price showen but not in the product view.

We have a Customer Group that gets a discount of the color white & black of product a

We setup a catalog price rule like that:

If any of this conditions is true:

Color choose is white Color choose is black

Get 10% off white and black.

And is there a solution to get this for the tier price to?